# Why Ubuntu fails to attach machine to https://ubuntu.com/advantage for enabling livepatch

Tags: 22.04, canonical-livepatch

My newly upgraded Jammy 22.04 lts failed to attach machine to https://ubuntu.com/advantage
attaching and detaching are not possible.

```
Failed to connect to authentication server
Check your Internet connection and try again.
Failed to attach machine. See https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

Another output

```
 ua status
SERVICE          AVAILABLE  DESCRIPTION
cc-eal           no         Common Criteria EAL2 Provisioning Packages
cis              yes        Center for Internet Security Audit Tools
esm-infra        yes        UA Infra: Extended Security Maintenance (ESM)
fips             yes        NIST-certified core packages
fips-updates     yes        NIST-certified core packages with priority security updates
livepatch        yes        Canonical Livepatch service
```

**This machine is not attached to a UA subscription.
See https://ubuntu.com/advantage**

Synaptic says,

W: https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/jammy-infra-security/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/jammy-infra-updates/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

There is no other issues with network connectivity. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Did you actually confirm that livepatch is *not* working? I also get the message *"This machine is not attached to a UA subscription"*, but livepatch *is* working.

Comment: No Livepatch icon or notification appears on the title bar. "Failed to attach machine. See https://ubuntu.com/advantage" message shows each time. I can't connect it using the Machine Token. I think the problem is with cc-eal or network.

Comment: Using dconf-editor I managed to show it on the title bar........it has a green indication. i think it is working.  But why I can't attach my machine using the Machine token?

Comment: But I think I do not get the facility form https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/jammy-infra-security/InRelease
https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/jammy-infra-updates/InRelease (Since the error message in the Synaptic)